# Spring Boot Data JPA - Not saving entities to the database

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application using JPA that has 2 datasources, 1 for DB2 and 1 for SQL Server.

When I try to save an entity to SQL Server, no error is thrown, but the entity is not persisted to the database.  I do not see an insert being generated in the log.

Thanks in advance

Here is the code I execute to try and save the entity.
@Component

```
public class TestSave {

    @Autowired
    private BeercupMessageLogRepository repository;


    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("Testing Save ... ");

        // Save the message in the transaction log - TypeId = 1 for Quote
        BeercupMessageLog beercupMessage = new BeercupMessageLog(1,"THIS IS A TEST ...", false);
        beercupMessage = repository.save(beercupMessage);
        System.out.println("Testing save complete ....");

    }
}
```

Here is the sql Server configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.xxx.beverage.repository.sqlserver",entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class sqlserverConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="datasource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "sqlserver.datasource")
    public DataSource sqlserverDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="primary")
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlserverEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
         return builder.dataSource(sqlserverDataSource()).persistenceUnit("sqlServer").properties(jpaProperties())
                   .packages("com.boelter.beverage.model.sqlserver").build();     }

    private Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
         Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
         props.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy");
         props.put("hibernate.default_schema","dbo");
         return props;
     }
}
```

Here is the SQL Server Repository

public interface BeercupMessageLogRepository extends

```
CrudRepository<BeercupMessageLog, Long> {

    BeercupMessageLog findOne(Long id);
    List<BeercupMessageLog> findByMessageTypeId(Long messageTypeId);
    List<BeercupMessageLog> findAll();
```

Here is the DB2 configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.boelter.beverage.repository.db2",entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory
2", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager2")
public class db2Configuration {

    @Bean(name="db2DataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="secondary")
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory2")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
         return builder.dataSource(db2DataSource()).persistenceUnit("db2").properties(jpaProperties())
                   .packages("com.boelter.beverage.model.db2").build();     }

    private Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
         Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
         props.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy");
         //props.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy","org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
         //props.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema","R3QASDATA");
         //props.put("spring.jpa.show-sql","true");
         return props;
     }
}
```

Here is the entity.

```
package com.boelter.beverage.model.sqlserver;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
@Table (name="[BeercupMessageLog]")
@Entity
@Transactional
public class BeercupMessageLog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long    messageId;

    @Column(name="MessageTypeId", nullable = false)
    private long    messageTypeId;

    @Column(name="Processed", nullable = false)
    private boolean processed;

    // Set updatable and insertable to false so JPA does not try to pass a value.  The DB has a default
    // of the current date if no value is passed
    @Column(name="MessageDate", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Date    messageDate;

    @Column(name="MessageText", nullable = false)
    private String  messageText;

    protected BeercupMessageLog() {}

    public BeercupMessageLog(long messageTypeId, String messageText, boolean processed) {
        this.messageTypeId = messageTypeId;
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.processed = processed;
    }

    /**
     * @return the messageId
     */
    public long getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    /**
     * @param messageId the messageId to set
     */
    public void setMessageId(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the messageTypeId
     */
    public long getMessageTypeId() {
        return messageTypeId;
    }

    /**
     * @param messageTypeId the messageTypeId to set
     */
    public void setMessageTypeId(long messageTypeId) {
        this.messageTypeId = messageTypeId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the messageDate
     */
    public Date getMessageDate() {
        return messageDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param messageDate the messageDate to set
     */
    public void setMessageDate(Date messageDate) {
        this.messageDate = messageDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the processed
     */
    public boolean isProcessed() {
        return processed;
    }

    /**
     * @param processed the processed to set
     */
    public void setProcessed(boolean processed) {
        this.processed = processed;
    }

    /**
     * @return the messageText
     */
    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    /**
     * @param messageText the messageText to set
     */
    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "BeercupMessage[id=%d, typeId=%d, message='%s']",
                messageId, messageTypeId, messageText);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you add your entity to the question as well.

Comment: Yes, just added at the end .....

Answer (score 10):

I guess it's more your DB2 database which is not saved, because the problem is you need to set a custom `transactionManagerRef` for the database for which the datasource, entitymanager factory and transaction manager are not marked `@Primary`.
Here you configured `transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager2"` but you did not inject it in the configuration bean.

Just add to `db2Configuration` something like :

```
@Bean(name = "transactionManager2")
public PlatformTransactionManager accountTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    JpaTransactionManager tm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    tm.setEntityManagerFactory(db2EntityManagerFactory(builder).getObject());
    tm.setDataSource(db2DataSource());
    return tm;
}
```

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. I made a mistake like this, created the transactionManager bean but forget to add the transactionManagerRef on @EnableJpaRepositories annotation. The application was able to read the datasources registries, but unable to save new entities.

Comment: In my case, my problem is that I created `PlatformTransactionManager`  bean by `new DataSourceTransactionManager(getDataSource())`, It seems `BasicDataSourceTransactionManager` just does not work well with spring jpa(I used spring boot2 starter which bring in spring-data-jpa:2.0.12 ). Replacing it by `new JpaTransactionManager` solved my problem

Comment: Didn't knew that two different TMs are required when connecting to different databases. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, for me it was Spring Batch:

`public class BatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {`

The fact that I extended DefaultBatchConfigurer was creating a second EntityManager and so my data source was not persisting the data into the DB.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing your resolution

Comment: I commented this out and it worked for me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager` will also spoil the transactional database commit capability. So do not create `ResourcelessTransactionManager` as a bean.